# Custom WordPress theme ERROR - parsererror: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 2 column 12 of the JSON data

Tags: json, wordpress

I have searched for this error in every method. But I couldn't find an answer.

I have made a custom theme using understrap. Now after adding some plugins, it keeps on showing this error. Plugins that show this error are WPvividBackup and WPJobManager.

> parsererror: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 2 column 12 of the JSON data

After changing the theme to another default theme like twenty-twenty, there is no error. I have the link to the relevant page to the website I'm building, so you can see the error.

[Link To the Website](http://quickbookssrilanka.com/applicant-my-page/)

I think the error is in the functions page which I didn't even touch. I only made some page templates using the understrap framework. Please help me to figure out the error and solve this by not changing the whole theme templates again.

Answer (score 0):

for some reason this response is being converted into JSON and throwing the error which you see [image]

Comment: This image might help others too. Thank you. I'm trying my best to solve this. Because the company want this tomorrow.

Comment: the JSON seems related to the WPJobManager plugin since it mentions jobs

Comment: But the thing is, when I change the theme to default, it works. That means the problem is in the theme. I have no idea to find the place of the error.